Trying to install missing TeX packages in Ubuntu
Apparently, I have a missing package in my TeXLive installation.
(Since people prefer specificity here, the error is essentially LaTeX Error: File 'pdftexcmds.sty' not found. when trying to compile a document including the hyperref package.)
Doing a search for how to install missing packages, I find instructions to use tlmgr to install missing packages. However, using the command tlmgr install pdftexcmds I found here I get the following response:
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /home/name/texmf
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!

Opening the file indicated there, I find the message:
We strongly recommend **not** to user the TeX Live Manager user mode on Debian.
If you are using it despite the warnings, be prepared to fix your own TeX system.

The "documentation", meanwhile, is (as one might expect) a rather large document that is by no means easy to navigate with the limited navigational hints in the message above.
I find this confusing and frustrating. What is the intended method of downloading individual LaTeX packages? In particular, what steps should I have taken? Is there a step-by-step guide somewhere?

For my specific problem, I have also tried directly downloading pdftexcmds from CTAN but the downloaded zip folder does not appear to contain a .sty file, and putting it in the path hasn't resolved the problem. I am seeking answers to the above bolded question, but a hint of how to resolve my specific situation in the comments would be acceptable.

Check whether the package texlive-latex-base is installed. If you have installed TeXlive using the Debian package, it actually should be installed, as it is rather basic. Then check, whether you have /usr/share/texlive, and within it, /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty.

CTAN do not hold files which can be easily regenerated, which often includes .sty files. so you could likely make the sty from the package you downloaded, but it won't be included standalone. but it would be (much) better to fix your installation as the error you're getting says something is badly broken.

it would help to see the log file for a minimal example so we could see versions and so on.

You are using the debian system tex so update using your Linux pacjahnanzger eg sudo apt install texlive-latex-recommended

Hmm. On Ubuntu 24.04.1, apt-file find pdftexcmds.sty says it's in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty, installed by texlive-latex-base. So sudo apt install texlive-latex-base should do the trick...

@cfr Indeed, it seems that something went wrong in my installation, since multiple other basic packages were missing. This didn't prevent me from compiling documents with few package requirements, though, so if I knew a straightforward answer to my question I could have managed the omissions in a few minutes instead of the >40 mins required to reinstall TeX with thousands of packages I don't currently need.

@DavidCarlisle how did you find the name "texlive-latex-recommended"? Where should I have looked to find this? (Asking in case I need to install less basic packages in the future.)

it's a well-known debian package @MorganRogers and lots of other linux distros use the same or similar naming schemes for texlive packages. use apt to search for the word texlive in the database and you'll find a bunch of these. linux distros break the upstream complete scheme up into smaller packages. they then typically break tlmgr - in the case of debian/ubuntu, they really do a thorough job - and then distribute that way. (debian may also remove some files - not sure if they still do this.)

@MorganRogers I googled for "debian package pdftexcmds` to fint the apt package that contains that file, I think there are specific apt utilities but I'm not on an ubumtu machine and google usually works, I actually landed on https://packages.debian.org/sid/texlive-latex-recommended
